# TF 1.7: Not found: TF GPU device with id 0 was not registered

Tags: tensorflow

I built TF 1.7 libraries from source.
When I use it with rust binding I get

```
2018-04-16 23:40:09.254248: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-04-16 23:40:09.254550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7465
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 5.93GiB freeMemory: 4.95GiB
2018-04-16 23:40:09.254562: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-04-16 23:40:09.383859: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-04-16 23:40:09.383889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:917]      0 
2018-04-16 23:40:09.383894: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N 
2018-04-16 23:40:09.384066: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4711 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-04-16 23:40:09.463369: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:127] Not found: TF GPU device with id 0 was not registered
```

All look ok except the last line.
What is this the error? It doesn't appear in python.

Someone built TF 1.7 in Mac+python and got the same error: https://gist.github.com/pavelmalik/d51036d508c8753c86aed1f3ff1e6967

Comment: I got the same error messages on Ubuntu 16.04.4 using TF Java JNI Wrapper 1.7.0 (GPU version) with Cuda/CuDnn 9.0/7.0.5.However, I've checked and the TF program is running on my GPU (Tesla P100) as expected. I'm not sure but maybe this error message could be ignored.

Comment: Confirming that this can be ignored.